# In Fast R-CNN how are input RoIs mapped to the respective RoIs in the feature map before RoI pooling?

Tags: cnn, computer-vision

I've been reading the [Fast R-CNN paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1504.08083.pdf)

**My understanding is** that the input to one forward pass is the whole input image plus a list of RoIs (generated by selective search or another region proposal method). Then I understand that on the last convolution layer's feature map, each *corresponding* RoI gets RoI-pooled.

But I'm **having trouble with two concepts**:

1. How is the input RoI mapped to the corresponding RoI in the deep feature map? Each "pixel" in the feature map comes from a very a non-linear function on wide perceptive field over the input, so there's no way of making a 1:1 mapping right?
2. Disregarding that I'm confused in point 1, once we have a bunch of RoIs in FM and we do the RoI pooling, we have N pooled feature vectors. Do we now run each of these through one FC network one by one? Or do we have N branches of FC networks? (that wouldn't make sense to me)

**EDIT**

I also just finished reading the [Faster R-CNN paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1506.01497v3.pdf). In the same way, I'm also interested to know about how the proposed regions from RPN map to the input of the RoI pooling in the Fast R-CNN layers. Because actually those proposed regions live in the space of the input image, not in the space of the deep feature map.